# react native - can't get url from share intent

Tags: android, react-native, deep-linking

I want it to be possible to share web pages with my react native app. After the user will share with my app, I need to be able to extract the url.
This is part of my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
          <data android:scheme="https"/>
          <!-- note that the leading "/" is required for pathPrefix-->
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
          <data android:scheme="http"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
```

And this is my code in react native where I am trying to retrieve the url -

```
useEffect(() => {
        Linking.getInitialURL().then((url) => {
            if (url) {
              alert('got url ', url);
            }
        }).catch((e) => {
          alert('got some error ', e)
        });
      }, []);

useEffect(() => {
        const callback = (url) => alert("get url when app was open " + decodeURI(url));
        Linking.addEventListener('url', callback);
        return () => {
          Linking.removeEventListener('url', callback);
        };
      }, []);
```

There are 2 options here - one when the app is already open and the other when the app was opened by the share process.
I don't get the url in any of the options.
I am running the app on a real android devices attached to my laptop in non debug mode.
And it seems like the app keep refreshing itself all the time.

Can someone explain what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you're mixing up deep linking and share menu.
If you want to share urls to your app, you can use this extension https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-share-menu. This will add your app as a target while sharing from other apps/browser.

```
const handleShare = useCallback((item: ?SharedItem) => {
if (!item) {
  return;
}

const { mimeType, data, extraData } = item;

setSharedData(data);
setSharedMimeType(mimeType);
// You can receive extra data from your custom Share View
console.log(extraData);
}, []);
useEffect(() => {
    ShareMenu.getInitialShare(handleShare);},
[]);
```

You can find the url youre looking for in "data" field of "item: ?SharedItem"